# Microphone does work in Azure Speech to Text SDK using Eclipse, but seems not to work with IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, intellij-idea

first of all here the **link to the repo:**.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk

When I open the project using Eclipse and change the mandatory fields:

```
SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("myKey", "westus");
//westus is the service region
```

... all works fine.

After importing the Eclipse project to IntelliJ, converting it to a maven project and finally executing it, the program runs **but**

> there is no speech recognized, (I didn't even get the request from `Intellij`to grant Microphone permission) that might be the problem.

**Edit:**
I have Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ installed with a valid subscription, but it doesn't work either (still the same problem as stated above, it's strange because it works in Eclipse)

Any idea I work on Mac OS by the way? See below Screenshot of the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Do you have Azure toolkit installed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Try to directly set the microphone permission for IntelliJ by following these web pages [How to Change Application Permissions on a Mac](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Application-Permissions-on-a-Mac) and [How to prevent Mac apps from using your FaceTime camera & mic without permission on macOS Mojave](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/08/16/howto-mac-camera-microphone-permission/)